# How can I serve up a webpage across a network?

Tags: windows, internet, windows-server-2012

I work for a small company and we constantly access a site (mcmaster.com), and we place a group order at the end of the day. Since the carts are localized to computers we can't see each others carts even if we are under the same account. I tried doing an iframe inside a webpage that everyone could access but I think the website disallows using iframes in their code as it doesn't work. its a SOHO network, with a MS windows server running the network so everyone behind the network can at least see internal pages if that gives anyone ideas. Any solutions?

Comment: It's not necessarily possible. Have you considered designating one person to handle the order?

Comment: I realize it may not be possible, but I was hoping! we have, People come and go at different times so one person handling may not always, work. We also considered a white board, but I was just trying to find an elegant solution. Maybe one doesn't exist.

Comment: You could fool mcmaster into thinking you are all the same browser by sharing the identity cookie that it uses.  This is more apt to succeed if you all go through a common router (so the website sees the same IP address for all of you), use the same operating system and version, and the same revision of the same browser.   At least those are the fields my code checks to protect session key security.